# User model giving email validation error in loopback3

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback

I have created a model `MyUser` based on the `User` model as follows:

```
{
  "name": "MyUser",
  "base": "User",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "ownerRelations": true,
  "emailVerificationRequired": true,
  "hidden": [
    "email",
    "emailVerified"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "firstName": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "lastName": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "email": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "accessTokens": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "CustomAccessToken",
      "polymorphic": {
        "foreignKey": "userId",
        "discriminator": "principalType"
      },
      "options": {
        "disableInclude": true
      }
    }
  },
  "acls": [
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "DENY"
    },
    {
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "property": "create"
    }
  ],
  "methods": {}
}
```

It works perfectly on my local server. But when I host it on aws `ec2`, only the first time user is created. Next time even if I give different email id, I get email verification error as follows:

`The 'MyUser' instance is not valid. Details:`email`Email already exists (value: undefined).`

Now if I delete the 1st record and try to create user, it works. So, only 1st record is getting inserted and post that for any unique email also, I am getting validation error. I am not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the problem. I have kept `email` as a hidden field. loopback has `"prohibitHiddenPropertiesInQuery": true` by default which does not allow hidden properties in query. As a result, during user validation, `email` was ignored in the query in `loopback-juggler/lib/validation.js`. Upon setting `prohibitHiddenPropertiesInQuery` to false, it works.

However, I am still not sure why it was working in development mode on my local server. `prohibitHiddenPropertiesInQuery` is by default true, so it should not have worked in development mode also. If anyone have any answer to this, please do let me know.